# Как запустить веб-хост Asp.Net Core из соседнего проекта?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, selenium, nunit

Ранее мне удавалось запустить .Net Core 3.1 Asp.Net Core веб приложение из соседнего NUnit проекта так

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    Program.BuildWebHost(new string[] {}).Start();
}
```

А Program.cs в веб-приложении выглядит так

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Но после каких-то обновлений это перестало работать. Всё что я нашёл для NUnit, это совет использовать `WebApplicationFactory`

```
private WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
private HttpClient _client;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void GivenARequestToTheController()
{
    _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
    _client = _factory.CreateClient();
}
```

Это работает. Но не годится, если я не хочу использовать вот этот вот HttpClient, а хочу использовать Selenium, например.
Казалось бы, банальная задача запустить один проект из другого, но почему-то какие-то сложности.
Конечно, я могу вручную найти сборку и запустить процесс, но это же не серьёзно.

---

#### Дополнения

1. Под "перестало работать" я имею ввиду, что не слушаются порты 5000 и 5001,
   как должно быть по конфигурации. Не какие иные порты тоже не слушаются я просканировал весь localhost.
2. При запуске тестов в режиме Debug, я поставил точку остановки в Startup.cs и дошёл до конца без ошибок.

---

#### Обнаружил источник проблемы

Благодаря [примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165562/22836) [@Andrei Khotko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212981/andrei-khotko) удалось методом тыка найти источник проблемы. Воспроизводится она начинает после добавления следующего кода в **Startup.cs**

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ... 

    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")    
        .Build();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

Но почему так происходит, я не понимаю всё равно. Сначала подумал, что из-за отсутствия файла appsettins.json в тестовом проекте. Скопировал его туда, не помогает. Я проверил в отладчике, что `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` возвращает путь к папке, куда этот файл копируется при сборке.

В чём тогда может быть дело?

Comment: `Но после каких-то обновлений это перестало работать.` Как это проявляется? Выдает ошибку? Если да, то можете, пожалуйста, привести текст ошибки?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, К сожалению ничего не выдаёт. Может nunit проглатывает, не знаю. Проявляется в том что, не прослушиваются порты https 5001 и http 5000, и не какие другие тоже.

Comment: Попробуйте перед `webhostBuilder.Build()` явно прописать `UseUrls(testUrl)`.

Comment: Возможно, как-то связано с профилями. Запускается (Launch) в IIS или как Project?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov само веб-приложение через  IIS Express не запускается, ага. Только кэстрэл.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko попробовал не помогло

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а можно в мой код как-то явно добавить указание профиля?

Comment: На днях попробую воспроизвести эту ситуацию

Comment: Нашел статью по теме https://remibou.github.io/Automated-E2E-Tests-with-Selenium-and-ASPNET-Core-on-Azure-Devops/ ещё не проверял

Comment: Прошу прощения, только сейчас получилось найти время. Я попробовал создать с нуля ASP Net Core Web-приложение. Добавил свой DI и один Api-метод, который вызывал задиаеный менеджер, который возвращал строку. Создал тестовое приложение - **все работает**. Единственное что - вместо `IWebHostBuilder` использовал `IHostBuilder`, как в рекомендациях microsoft. Если интересно, размещу код в ответе

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, конечно интересно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы, описанной в вопросе (который раскрылся, по сути, только после последней правки), нужно было обеспечить сохранение исходной конфигурации. Для этого нужно воспользоваться методом `.AddConfiguration()`

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json")
   .AddJsonFile($"secrets.json")
   .AddConfiguration(Configuration)
   .Build();
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

---

P.S. Правда и это мне не помогло, но это уже тема для следующего вопроса [Не могу получить index.html из теста NUnit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168217/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-index-html-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-nunit) [blazor](/questions/tagged/blazor)[blazor-client-side](/questions/tagged/blazor-client-side)

Comment: Что-то тут не то. Как-то сложно выглядит ваша настройка конфигурации. Мне кажется, вы что-то не так делаете. Можете подробнее описать то, что вы пытаетесь сделать в вашем проекте?

Comment: ничего особого, просто несколько файлов с конфигурацией.

Answer (score 0):

Создал приложение ASP.NET Core Web Application по шаблону WebApi (.Net Core 3.1). Создал HelloDataManager:

```
namespace NetCoreWebAppSample.Managers
{
    public interface IHelloManager
    {
        string SayHelloTo(string name);
    }
}

namespace NetCoreWebAppSample.Managers
{
    public class HelloManager : IHelloManager
    {
        public string SayHelloTo(string name)
        {
            return $"Hello, {name}!";
        }
    }
}
```

Создал контроллер:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NetCoreWebAppSample.Managers;

namespace NetCoreWebAppSample.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HelloController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HelloController> _logger;
        private readonly IHelloManager _manager;

        public HelloController(IHelloManager manager, ILogger<HelloController> logger)
        {
            _manager = manager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{name}")]
        public string Get(string name)
        {
            var helloMessage = _manager.SayHelloTo(name);
            return helloMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace NetCoreWebAppSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

И создал сборку для тестов .Net Core 3.1 библиотека классов, в которую добавил класс:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NetCoreWebAppSample.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HelloWebApiTests
    {
        private const string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:50200";
        private HttpClient _httpClient;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            var arguments = new string[0];
            var builder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(arguments);

            _httpClient = new HttpClient();

            builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w => w.UseUrls(serviceUrl)).Build().Start();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task UserShouldBeAbleToGetHelloMessage()
        {
            const string userName = "Andrei";
            var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/hello/{userName}";

            const string expected = "Hello, Andrei!";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            var actual = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Тест был пройден:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, за что минус поставили) во люди добрые)

Comment: Спасибо вам. Но не помогло, видать какая-то проблема в проекте.