# Не могу получить index.html из теста NUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, blazor, blazor-client-side

Я пытаюсь написать end-end тест используя NUnit для моего Blazor WebAssembly Asp.Net-core-hosted приложения.

Cоздал проект на основе шаблона 3.1.7.
Затем добавил NUnit проект в решение и написал простой тест.

```
private const string serviceUrl = "https://localhost:50200";
private HttpClient _httpClient;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Init()
{
    var arguments = new string[0];
    var builder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(arguments);

    _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    builder
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w => w.UseUrls(serviceUrl))
        .Build()
        .Start();
}

[Test]
public async Task HomePageResponcesOk()
{            
    var requestUrl = serviceUrl;
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

[Test]
public async Task ApiResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/WeatherForecast";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Больше ничего не менял.

Получил следующий результат.

```
Test                        Duration  Error Message
HomePageResponcesOk Failed  45 ms     Expected: OK   But was:  NotFound 
ApiResponcesOk      Passed  364 ms
```

Я делаю что-то не так?

Могу заметить также, что всё это работало в более ранних версиях Blazor WebAssembly.

---

Добавил ещё тесты

```
[Test]
public async Task AppCssResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/css/app.css";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

[Test]
public async Task WebAssemblyResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Тоже самое `Failed  45 ms     Expected: OK   But was:  NotFound`.
Может быть `app.UseStaticFiles();` работает не так, как я ожидаю?

---

Попробовал переделать тесты c использованием
`WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().CreateClient()` вместо `Program.CreateHostBuilder(arguments);`

```
private const string serviceUrl = "";
private WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;    
private HttpClient _httpClient;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Init()
{
    _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
    _httpClient = _factory.CreateClient();
}
```

Все тесты проходят! Но мне такой вариант не подойдёт, т.к. я планирую использовать Selenium.

---

Получается, что при запуске из проекта с тестами, бэкэнд почему-то не знает, где собственно находиться *wwwroot*. Лечиться с помощью `UseWebRoot()`

```
builder
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w =>
    {
        w.UseUrls(serviceUrl);
        w.UseWebRoot(@"..\..\..\..\BlazorApp2\Client\wwwroot");
    })
   .Build()
   .Start();
```

Все тесты теперь проходят, кроме `WebAssemblyResponcesOk`. Оно и понятно: файл находится в другом каталоге `\BlazorApp2\Client\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\wwwroot\_framework`

Но если добавить ещё один `.UseWebRoot()` он просто отменит действие первого

---

Что ж я полез глубже отладчиком в исходники Asp.Net Core.

Наблюдается следующее.
Если запускать проект бэкэнда, то полю `_fileProvider` класса `StaticFileMiddleware` присваивается значение со следующей структурой

```
CompositeFileProvider-- ._fileProviders
                               |                  
                               +-- NullFileProvider
                               |
                               +-- StaticWebAssetsFileProvider-- .InnerProvider
                                                                       |
                                                             PhysicalFileProvider
                               |
                               +-- StaticWebAssetsFileProvider-- .InnerProvider
                                                                       |    
                                                             PhysicalFileProvider
```

Один `PhysicalFileProvider` нацелен на *wwwroot* в исходниках, другой на *wwwroot* в `/bin`

Если же запускать тесты, то `StaticFileMiddleware` `_fileProvider` получает просто `PhysicalFileProvider` нацеленный на путь указанный в аргументе `UseWebRoot()`. Если же вернуться к варианту без `UseWebRoot()`, то получим вовсе `NullFileProvider`.

Теперь очень прояснилась первоначальная картина. Но тем не менее всё же вовсе не ясно, что же именно влияет на то, что получит StaticFileMiddleware в качестве поставщика файлов. В конструктор класса значение попадает с помощью инъекции типа `IOptions<StaticFileOptions>`. Но где мне ставить точки останова, чтобы поймать регистрацию в DI для этого типа, я не понимаю.

Comment: А браузер по адресу `https://localhost:50200` что открывает?

Comment: @aepot Ничего не открывает, если запуск из nunit

Comment: @aepot браузерное сообщение о HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: В таком случае с тестами все нормально. Что-то с сервером не так.

Comment: Не работал с Blazor WebAssembly. Посмотрел различные туториалы. Вы уверены, что у вас проект типа Blazor WebAssembly, а не Blazor Server?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в пайплайн конфигурации `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();`, затем, если нужен доступ к статическим файлам `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko. Да, конечно, уверен. Полгода уже как работаю с Blazor WASM.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko. Эти мидлвари входят в шаблонный Startup.cs. Или куда вы говорите мне надо добавить? Не совсем понимаю, что такое *пайплайн конфигурации*

Comment: @4per я просто сейчас создал проект WASM - в нем нет никакого Startup.cs. Видимо, что-то поменялось с новой версией .Net Core 3.1. Про пойплайн имел ввиду в классе Startup метод `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` или что-то подобное, где передается IApplicationBuilder. Проблема скрыта именно в методе настройки пайплайна http-запроса. Чего-то не зватает, либо стоит не в том порядке, в котором должно. Какой версии у вас приложение?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Вы наверное не поставили галку **Asp.Net Core Hosted". Таким образом, создали только само WASM-приложение (фронтэнд) без бэкэнда. Приложение по шаблону 3.1.7 версия 3.2.1

Comment: Да, вы правы! В этом случае там создается 2 приложения: Server + Client. И в сервере, как раз, находится Startup.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Скопировал из `...\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` в `...\NUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` файлы *.StaticWebAssets.xml
2. Добавил `UseStaticWebAssets()` в код запуска бэкэнда.

   ```
   builder
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w =>
    {
        w.UseUrls(serviceUrl);
        w.UseStaticWebAssets();
    })
   .Build()
   .Start();
   ```

Теперь все тесты проходят, а отладчик показывает инъекцию `CompositeFileProvider` почти с той же структурой, как при ручном запуске бэкэнда..

Настроил копирование этих файлов в событиях построения

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy ..\Rest\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0-windows\*.StaticWebAssets.xml .\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0-windows\*.*" />
</Target>
```

К сожалению, не могу понять, как настроить генерацию этих файлов в проекте тестов автоматически.